# Magento CE 1.9.2 - Spanish (Spain) Language Pack

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, language-package

I have looked everywhere trying to find the Spanish (Spain) Language Pack for Magento. I found several resources and one in particular where all language packs for the old resource that used to be supported by Magento are now housed.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140717210430/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/

However, I can't find the Spanish (Spain) version. It is listed, but not available for download (I receive a 301 error). Anyone else find a different location to download the CE Magento 1.9.2 edition? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: https://crowdin.com/project/magento-1/es#

Notes:

- this is not exactly for 1.9.2 (guess it's for 1.9), so you should compare translations with Magentos files in `en_US` folder and search for missing translations
- this pack contains some files you don't need, e.g. all with `Enterprise_` prefix and some others like `Mage_Ogone.csv`

<sup>If you use this and add translations, think about to upload it there ... mayybe it helps others :)</sup>

Comment: I saw that link and didn't see any folders available for locale or design like the other language packs I have downloaded from the archived site. Agree that there should be some differentiation between CE and Enterprise on that site. I'll dig into it and see what I can use. Thanks for re-affirming what I found!

Comment: @KristinMarkell did it work for you? ES package seems to nearly complete.

Comment: Yes. I am all set. I looked around a bit further but that was the best package to use! Appreciate the direction.